# How to use webpack-hot-server-middleware with Firebase functions in express

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, webpack, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use cloud functions for Firebase in a Server side rendering React Project.

First, when I trying running express server with babel-watch in webpack is working! So I want to be able to make firebase functions in express server with babel-watch, I read [functions-samples/isomorphic-react-app/](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/isomorphic-react-app) repository and make below codes. but maybe I don't understand..

So, Is there a way using webpack-hot-server-middleware with `functions.https.onRequest(app);` using `babel-watch` in developing ?

Or Is correct `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` in my case?

#### server/index.js

```js
import express from "express";
import webpack from "webpack";
import webpackDevMiddleware from "webpack-dev-middleware";
import webpackHotServerMiddleware from "webpack-hot-server-middleware";
import clientConfig from "../webpack/client";
import serverConfig from "../webpack/server";

const app = express();
const compiler = webpack([clientConfig, serverConfig]);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(webpackHotServerMiddleware(compiler));

export let firebaseTrigger = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

#### webpack/server.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  name: "server",
  target: "node",
  entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../server/render.js")],
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../functions"),
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

#### firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "firebaseTrigger"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "react-firebase",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "functions/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "NODE_ENV=development babel-watch server/index.js",
    "dev-server": "firebase serve --only functions,hosting"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-watch": "^2.0.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.16.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-server-middleware": "^0.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not firebase functions, it's the hosting.

Firebase function already contains hot reload when running locally. As you can read on their documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

> For both tools, code changes you make during an active session are automatically reloaded by the emulator. If your code needs to be transpiled (TypeScript, React) make sure to do so before running the emulator.

But for the hosting part it does not really work(yet):
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/594

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to not use the Firebase Emulator and just use the firestore and functions emulators with your existing dev server. Run your dev server and the emulator at the same time.

```js
import firebaseSettings from '../../firebase.json'
// other imports

const firebaseConfig = { /* add config */ }

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
firebase.auth() // never emulated

const isDev = location.hostname === 'localhost'

if (isDev) {
  // Emulator/Development settings
  const firestorePort = firebaseSettings.emulators.firestore.port
  const functionsPort = firebaseSettings.emulators.functions.port
  const firestoreUrl = `localhost:${firestorePort}`
  const functionsUrl = `http://localhost:${functionsPort}`
  firebase.firestore().settings({
    host: firestoreUrl,
    ssl: false,
    experimentalForceLongPolling: true, // this is used by cypress
  })
  // if app uses callable functions
  firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator(functionsUrl)
} else {
  // Production settings
  firebase.firestore()
  firebase.functions()
}
```